# Android back button not navigating back, just refreshing activity

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I'm not sure what code to post here.  Basically I have these activities:

- Activity A (List)
- Activity B (Add New Item)
- Activity C (Item Details)

The main flow is like:

A-->B-->A-->C-->A

On Navigation from B-->A or C-->A I am also calling finish() method because I don't want to have any back button navigation to those screens.

However **the issue I have now is when you follow the main flow and land on Activity A and then click Android back button, it just refreshes Activity A.**  It does this for a couple clicks before navigating out of the app.

Any suggestions here? It seems related to the number of activities you go to before landing on Activity A, but I don't know how to debug this or fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement that on navigating from B to A you are "also" calling `finish()` suggests that B is launching a new A.  If so, that's the problem.  If your activity stack looked like this:

```
B
A
```

...and B launched a new A and then called `finish()`, your activity stack would look like this:

```
A
A
```

Upon pressing the back button, it might appear to be "refreshing" A.  In fact, it would be showing you different copies of A stacked on top of one another until you reach the bottom of the stack and the app finally exits.  To get the intended behavior, B should call `finish()` without starting a new copy of A.

Comment: Yes this x100.  That makes perfect sense, because I was doing: 
`Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.FoodList)
startActivity(intent)
finish()`  So now if I take out the intent and leave the finish, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Actually back button will automatically call finsh().
I guess you have start new Activity A before finishing B or C .Else  you could call some method like navigateUpFromSameTask().Make sure you have set parent Activity in manifest